# Keep Getting InteropServices.COMException when running Word from ASP MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, com, office-interop

I get the error the remote procedure call failed HRESULT: 0x800706BE exception when running Microsoft.Interop.Word from a controller in my ASP .NET MVC application. The strange thing is that if I debug the application and run it step by step, no exception is thrown. I haven't been able to understand the few documentation I've found on microsoft about this exception. I read is has to do with Word closing the sockets when it's called, but I'm at a loss to understand anything about it, so I hope someone may know what the problem may be. The exception is always thrown at a specific line of my code (I've commented where it fails):

```
//
    // GET /Asistencia/PrintDocentes
    public ActionResult PrintDocentes(int IdCurso)
    {
        List<AsistenciaDocentesViewModel> materias = new Metodos.Entidades().getListadoProfesores(IdCurso);
        List<int> compartidas = new List<int>();
        compartidas = materias.GroupBy(t => t.IdMateriasCursos).Where(t => t.Count() > 1).Select(t => t.Key).ToList();
        List<string> catedrasCompartidas = new List<string>();
        catedrasCompartidas= materias.Where(s => compartidas.Any(t=> t.Equals(s.IdMateriasCursos))).Select(r => r.NombresMaestro).ToList();

        string document = "asistenciaDocentes.docx";
        string uploadsFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/Docs");
        string imageFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/Docs");
        string[] encabezado = { "logoCideAsistencia.jpg", "logoSegobAsistencia.jpg", "logoPFAsistencia.jpg", "logoDiplomadoAsistencia.jpg" };
        string archivo = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, @document);
        ApWord = new Word.Application();
        docAsistencia = ApWord.Documents.Add(ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc);
        ApWord.Visible = true;
        docAsistencia.PageSetup.RightMargin = (float)100;
        docAsistencia.PageSetup.LeftMargin = (float)60;
        foreach (Word.Section section in ApWord.ActiveDocument.Sections)
        {
            Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            for (int i = 0; i < encabezado.Length; i++)
            {
                headerRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
                string path = Path.Combine(imageFolder, encabezado[i]);
                Word.InlineShape map = headerRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path);
                if (i == 0) { map.Height = 48; map.Width = 39; } /*********
*********************This is the line that throws the exception ********/
                if (i == 1) { map.Width = 263; map.Height = 39; }
                if (i == 2) { map.Width = 141; map.Height = 26; }
                headerRange.Move(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter);
                headerRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
                if (i == 2) break;

            }

            Word.Shape titulo = docAsistencia.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,60, 5, 300, 50, ref opc);
            titulo.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "DIPLOMADO EN MANDO POLICIAL 2015\nLista de Asistencia de profesores\n";
            titulo.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
            titulo.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Cambria";
            titulo.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 16;
            titulo.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = 1;
            titulo.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic = 1;


            headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
            Word.InlineShape map2 = headerRange.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Path.Combine(imageFolder, encabezado[3]));
            map2.Height = 106;
            map2.Width = 137;


        }
        foreach(AsistenciaDocentesViewModel item in materias)
        {
        Word.Paragraph grupo1 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add(ref opc);
        grupo1.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
        grupo1.Range.Font.Size = 14;
        grupo1.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
        grupo1.Range.InsertAfter("Semana\t" + item.Semana);
        Word.Paragraph grupo2 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo2.Range.InsertAfter("Sede\t" + item.Sede);
        Word.Paragraph grupo3 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo3.Range.InsertAfter("Grupo\t" + item.Grupo);
        Word.Paragraph grupo4 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        docAsistencia.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdLineBreak);
        grupo4.Range.InsertAfter("Fecha\t" + item.Fecha);
        Word.Paragraph grupo5 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo5.Range.InsertAfter("Día\t" + item.Dia);
        Word.Paragraph grupo6 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo6.Range.InsertAfter("Horario\t" + item.HorarioInicio + " - " + item.HorarioFin);
        Word.Paragraph grupo7 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo7.Range.InsertAfter("compartir");

        if (compartidas.Contains(item.IdMateriasCursos))
        {
            List<AsistenciaDocentesViewModel> compartir = materias.Where(t => t.IdMateriasCursos.Equals(item.IdMateriasCursos)).ToList();
            List<string> catedras = compartir.Select(t => t.NombresMaestro).ToList();
            List<string> catedras_aImprimir = catedras.Where(t => !t.Equals(item.NombresMaestro)).ToList();
            foreach (string catedra in catedras_aImprimir)
            {
                Word.Paragraph grupo8 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
                grupo8.Range.InsertAfter(catedra);

            }
            docAsistencia.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdLineBreak);
        }
        Word.Paragraph grupo9 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo9.Range.InsertAfter("Módulo");
        Word.Paragraph grupo10 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add(); 
        grupo10.Range.InsertAfter(item.Modulo);
        Word.Paragraph grupo11 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo11.Range.InsertAfter("Materia");
        Word.Paragraph grupo12 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo12.Range.InsertAfter(item.Materia);
        Word.Paragraph grupo13 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo13.Range.InsertAfter("Profesor");
        Word.Paragraph grupo14 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo14.Range.InsertAfter(item.NombresMaestro);
        Word.Paragraph grupo15 = docAsistencia.Paragraphs.Add();
        grupo15.Range.InsertAfter("Firma:______________________________________________________");

        docAsistencia.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
        }
        docAsistencia.SaveAs2(archivo, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc,
            ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc, ref opc);
        docAsistencia.Close();
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ApWord);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(docAsistencia);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        return RedirectToAction("VerRecursos", new { file = document });

    }
```

Please help, I haven't worked with Interop before so I really can't guess what's wrong, I thought maybe the two for cycles may cause the problem, but I really have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Consider using Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for more information. Also you may find third-party components that are designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: Yes, I've read it, but if you read my code, I don't leave the application unattended. The only missing line would read like this: `docAsistencia.Close();
            ApWord.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ApWord);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(docAsistencia);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();` and thus, I don't leave any process open. Your answer doesn't answer my question, because I want to know exactly what characteristics may be usable on the server side. My hosting company say they support interop.

Comment: Anyway, I have ended up commenting all the lines that assign witdh and height to the picture I add, like this: `if (i == 0) { map.Height = 48; map.Width = 39; }` because that's what was causing the problem. What I want is some insight on why this behavior may happen, other than "Your computer may have virus". Oddly enough, it's just the first three lines that assign width and height that fail, the last one i. e. `map2.Height = 106;
            map2.Width = 137;` doesn't cause any problem. What would you recommend to learn more about com and remote procedure calls?

Comment: Thanks, I've also read about the Open XML SDK and it seems all that is required is to know the basic classes like paragraph, text, run etc. But I'm curious on how do you publish the xml document (is it readable from word?)

Comment: @gerardoflores, you misunderstand the meaning of "unattended" in this context. "Unattended" means that there is no human present who can, for example, click on a message box. But it's more complicated than that. Word was designed, programmed and tested to run with a person sitting in front of it with a monitor, keyboard and mouse. A service (like a web server) behaves differently from a user interactive desktop in subtle ways, and that will trip Word in ways the Office developers did not anticipate. It doesn't matter how carefully you try to program it via automation, Word will likely break.

Comment: Sorry if I say a nonsense, I am not sure about the language but, can it be that map is a reserved word in that context? I see that map is in cyan in the first loop, and map2 (which you say works fine) is black.